# Are there any proven ways to increase the rate of bone remodeling in humans?

Tags: bone-biology, bone

I'm not asking for anything specific -- just wondering if there's any data, studies, or etc. that show a possibility in increased bone resorption and turnover (bone remodeling/Wolff's Law) from certain procedures (whether it be diet, supplementation, drugs, surgery/experimentation, exercise/habits, etc.)

For example, comparisons between studies of people that show bone remodeling faster under different circumstances that can prove a specific method one can use to apply

By "increase" I mean anything that allows the human skeleton to be replaced faster some way

Comment: How can I clarify to make it sound as if I'm not asking for something specific then?

Comment: There, I clarified -- check the new title.

Answer (score 2):

The main factors affecting bone remodelling are the person's age, and the load applied on the bone. It is known that in relation to fracture healing, younger children remodel much faster and more effectively. This allows surgeons to accept very displaced fractures in young children without having to restore original anatomy as remodelling will take care of that naturally. Here is an example:

http://www.brokenarmanswers.com/arm-still-crooked-cast-comes-off/arm-fracture-remodeling-children/

The reason is that bone absorbs in areas under less loading, and forms along load lines. The shape of bones therefore follows the shape and alignment of surrounding muscles, which apply some form of load even at rest due to muscle tone. The process of bone absorption and formation is much more efficient and faster in younger people and becomes slower with age. This also explains why bones become osteoporotic in people who can't weight-bear for a lengthy period of time, or in astronauts who spend long periods in zero gravity.

A well known method to accelerate fracture healing is to load the fracture as early as possible. This is the main principle of the dynamic compression plates where the holes of the plate are designed as oval rather than circular, so that when an off-centred screw is tightened, it pulls the plate in a direction that results in compressing the fracture to promote bone healing. Here is an illustration to demonstrate this technique:

https://www2.med.wayne.edu/diagRadiology/RSNA2003/Compression_Plates_Overview.htm